# Is is possible to change a path's root folder with .htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website set up with its own root directory in the common configuration:

`mywebsite.com --> /path/www/mywebsite`

And them pathnames on mywebsite get naturally mapped to their corresponding subdirectory:

```
mywebsite.com/folder_a/ --> /www/mywebsite/folder_a/
mywebsite.com/folder_b/ --> /www/mywebsite/folder_b/
mywebsite.com/folder_c/ --> /www/mywebsite/folder_c/
... and so on
```

I would like to change the location for one of such subdirectories, so I could do something similar to:

```
mywebsite.com/folder_a/ --> /www/mywebsite/folder_a/
mywebsite.com/folder_b/ --> /some_other_path_on_my_server/
mywebsite.com/folder_c/ --> /www/mywebsite/folder_c/
... and so on
```

Although I know I can solve this by using a symlink to the other path, I would prefer to have this explicitly set up on my .htaccess file.

Is this possible? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with `.htaccess` alone since the file-path you are wanting to "rewrite" to is *outside* of the domains `DocumentRoot`.

In `.htaccess` (a *directory* context), the *substitution* string represents a URL-path, not a file-path.

You can do this if you have access to the server config (virtualhost). In a *server* or *virtualhost* context you can rewrite to an absolute *file-path*. However, if you have access to the server config then you would configure this as an `Alias` instead - you wouldn't use mod_rewrite.

Comment: Thank you, I was afraid of it not being possible, but an answer is an answer nonetheless.